# How to query multiple models in the same query in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is the SQL query I have been trying to convert using Django but I cannot figure out how to query multiple models together :

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.*,EMPLOYEE.*,PERSON.*
FROM EMPLOYEE,DEPARTMENT,PERSON
WHERE
EMPLOYEE.ID = :ID and
PERSON.ID = EMPLOYEE.ID and
EMPLOYEE.UNIT = DEPARTMENT.UNIT
```

Comment: Show your models

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use [select related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)